# Image with link moves a little to the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a masonry gallery and as the title says when I click on an image, the column moves a little bit to the bottom.

Already tried setting the margin, padding and text-decoration to a:hover, a:active, a:visited to 0.
Only happens when I click the image at the top, if I click the image in the middle or in the bottom it does not happens.

Thanks in advance for taking some time to help!

Comment: replicate your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ykbcf6y/2/
It does not happen in the first column tho

Comment: You added unnecessary `</li>` on your fiddle on line number 16.

Comment: That's not the problem, but thanks for pointing that out!
http://jsfiddle.net/4ykbcf6y/3/